# Sqlite prefix columns name

Tags: sqlite

in my project, I use a sqlite database.
When I perform a query, I use sqlite3_column_name(compiledStatement, i) to get the name of a column, and fetch the result in a NSArray of NSDictionnaries.

But when I use joins, I have some ambiguous columns name, and SQLITE doesn't anything.
Is there a way to get prefixed columns name to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename output columns:

```
SELECT a.x AS ax,
       b.x AS bx,
       [...]
FROM a JOIN B ...
```